# Can someone identify this stinging plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I have no idea where this plant came from, or what it is. What I do know is its leaves are covered in little hairs, there's little thorns growing all over it, and just by rubbing its leaf it burns you and leaves a red mark as well as blisters. It stung my mother and I would like to know what it is so I can find a remedy.

[image]

larger image:

http://i1094.photobucket.com/albums/i449/cupcaketurtle1/20150714_225505_zpskr24gklq.jpg

Comment: It would help if you could add in what country you mother was stung by this plant.

Comment: *The littles hairs* are called trichomes :) I had bad experience when visiting a tropical bushy area. If you don't mind, could you please share where (roughly the region and city) your mother came into to contact with this plant?

Comment: Looks like a member of Urticaceae.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a common stinging nettle, [*Urtica dioica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica). It is a native to Europe, Asia, northern Africa, and western North America and is the best-known member of the nettle genus *Urtica*. As commented by others, your geographical location would be helpful to obtain a more accurate identification.

Like other stinging nettles, it is unpleasant to the touch, but harmless. Just be patient. [The redness and burning/itching will disappear](http://www.healthdirect.gov.au/stinging-plants). If the pain gets serious or other complaints arise, go to your GP.

[image: stinging nettle]
<sup>Stinging nettle. Source: [Health Direct](http://www.healthdirect.gov.au/stinging-plants).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It's a nettle (genus [Urtica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica)).

The one on your photo really looks like the one I'm used to see in France:
[Urtica dioica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica).

I read in herbal lore books that the sting of the nettle could be appeased by rubbing it with [Plantago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago) leafs. But that might just be placebo effect.
See also [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_dioica#Nettle_sting_treatment) of the wikipedia page.

Comment: Common folklore where I live is to sooth the irritation by rubbing the affected area with the leaves of Dock ([Rumex obtusifolius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex_obtusifolius)) - which often grow near nettles. As a child I recall it being effective (though some of that was probably psychological reassurance).